# postgreSQL - set implicit start value for sequences

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql database, and i have a table with id_table column and type: serial, it automatically creates a new sequence for the column, but it always starts with settings (minimum value=1, start value=1 -> so the next value is 2), so..in every table my first row has id two and not one, isn't it strange?? i think everyone is used to start with value 1 and not 2, i can manually change the starting value, but i would like to ask you if you know how to change the implicit starting value for every new sequence to 1. Or at least why they did it so. thanks.

Comment: Surely start value 1 means that the first row inserted will get a  1? It's certainly not my experience that serial IDs in general start at 2.

Comment: Yes, surely, that's what I'm talking about, start value is implicitly 1 so the next value is 2 (should be 1 i think)

Comment: Can't reproduce this in 9.3 or 8.4; first id is always 1. What version of Postgres are you running?

Comment: Here's an SQLFiddle example of the first value being 1, as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e406/1

Comment: I'm using version 9.3.4

Comment: oh, i think i get it, when i created new table it was minimum=1,current value=1, next value=1, but when i insert some rows, then i truncate table and sequence, so then it counts from 2..

Comment: Yep, truncate doesn't do anything to reset the sequence. You might not want it to - for instance if the IDs had previously appeared in URLs, you'd want them to 404 rather than being reused with different content.

Answer (score 1):

When I create a table like this . . .

```
create table your_table (
  id serial primary key
);
```

PostgreSQL creates this sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_table_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

If I then insert a row, and look at the value . . .

```
insert into your_table values (default);
select * from your_table;
```

```
id
--
1
```

This is the documented behavior, and it's what I'd expect.

You can [truncate a table and restart the sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-truncate.html) in PostgreSQL 8.4+.

```
truncate your_table restart identity;
insert into your_table values (default);
select * from your_table;
```

```
id
--
1
```

Comment: yes, but try truncated my table, and then i wanted to "restart" sequence, i had to change minvalue and start value because second time it started from 2, my fault.

Comment: You can truncate and restart in a single SQL statement. See edited answer.